# jQuery dynamically call event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a big Problem: 
I have many Div Containers on my Page with the class ".element" which I make draggable using jQuery. 
Now I have the possibility to dynamically create divs with the class "element", and I want to make them draggable as well. 
So I thought: Simple solution: I just call

$(".element").draggable();

again. But: The whole listener is executed twice then, which unacceptable for me because it sends AJAX-Requests and i don't want them to be sent twice.

So I started to make Functions to call draggable only on the newly created element, which is kind of stupid I guess.

So my question: Is there any better possibility since the live()-Method is deprecated (which was a big mistake in my opinion!)

Please help me!

Kind regards,
David

Comment: you can use "on" instead of live

Comment: Just to note, 'on' does not necessarily work like 'live'. I've found that to attach listeners to dynamically created elements in lieu of 'live' you need to use on in this manner: $('body').on('click', '#myElement', function(){//do stuff});. 'body' can be replaced with any container element depending on how granular you want to get. To target everything you can just use document instead of 'body'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution could be to use a `data-attr` as flag

```
$(".element:not(data-draggable='1')")
    .draggable()
    .attr("data-draggable","1");
```

Note: `live` method is deprecated but you can use `on`.

Answer (score 2):

use    `event.stopPropagation()`

in your event..it will stop event to trigger twice....

i hope it work for you...